# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.slideshowapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android

**MainActivity.java**

I'm new to android studio and I'm trying to make a simple slideshow app with a spinner that sets the duration of the slideshow. I followed a couple YouTube videos to the dot and they didn't have any errors. The only thing I changed is setting the period in the handler taking it from the spinner but that doesn't seem to work. I'll take a fix or a different method that's  sure fire to work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    long duration;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    SlideShowAdapter adapter;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
    Timer timer;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.duration, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.imageView_id);
        adapter = new SlideShowAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

                if(i == adapter.images.length-1){

                    i=0;
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,true);
                }else {
                    i++;
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(i, true);
                }
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(runnable);
            }
        },duration,duration);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                duration = 3000;
                break;
            case 1:
                duration = 4000;
                break;
            case 2:
                duration = 5000;
                break;
            case 3:
                duration = 6000;
                break;
            case 4:
                duration = 7000;
                break;
        }
        text = String.valueOf(duration);;
        Toast.makeText(this,text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        duration = 4000;
    }

}
```

**Error/Crash**
I'm not using the OnClickListener but I keep getting an error about that. I think that's what the problem is.

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.slideshowapp, PID: 6139
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slideshowapp/com.example.slideshowapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.slideshowapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.slideshowapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener
        at com.example.slideshowapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7817)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7806)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 spinner.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);
```

is incorrect. You don't need the casting, thats the whole point of implementing the interface. Just call it:

```
 spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```